# Can you use SK3DNode to show a 3D model (.usdz) in SpriteKit project?

Tags: sprite-kit

I am trying to figure out how to implement a 3D model into my SpriteKit game. I'm not going to do anything crazy with the model, I just want to be able to spin it and zoom in & out.
I've seen a bunch of tutorials & write-ups on how to easily do this in SceneKit, but nothing for SpriteKit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can easily add a USDZ to your SpriteKit scene.

[image]

### Step 1

First of all drag your usdz model into the Xcode Project.

[image]

### Step 2

Next go to your SpriteKit scene and create a 3D node with the model

```
let node = SK3DNode(viewportSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))
node.scnScene = SCNScene(named: "R2-D2.usdz")
addChild(node)
```

### Full code

Here's the full code

```
import SpriteKit
import SceneKit

final class GameScene: SKScene {
    
    private let node: SK3DNode = {
        let node = SK3DNode(viewportSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))
        node.scnScene = SCNScene(named: "R2-D2.usdz")
        return node
    }()
    
    let label: SKLabelNode = {
        let label = SKLabelNode(text: "This is 2D Text from SpriteKit")
        label.position.y = 50
        label.fontColor = .black
        return label
    }()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        backgroundColor = .lightGray
        anchorPoint = .init(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        addChild(label)
        addChild(node)
    }
}
```

### Credits

I took the 3D model from [here](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/star-wars-r2-d2-bipedal-c78294a4a4064c4fb63d47c4dd749e02).